# $_SESSION login errors even though its set

Tags: php, session

My login works and verifys but will not set the `$_SESSION` it used to when i would attempt to access a blocked page and redirect to the login page then it would work properly but i deleted that page but it gets into the if statement and if i print the `$_SESSION` after i set (before the redirect home) it it acts as though it works but the `$_SESSION` doesn't save

```
if($login_ok)
{
    unset($row['salt']);
    unset($row['password']);

    $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
    echo '<script>window.location="/index.php";</script>';
    die("Redirecting to: index.php");
}
else
{
    print("Login Failed.");
    $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

connections page

```
   $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
    {
        foreach($array as &$value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);
            }
            else
            {
                $value = stripslashes($value);
            }
        }
    }

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);
}

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
```

Comment: are you setting `session_start()` at the top of every page you are trying to access the session from?

Comment: yes it is in my connection required

Comment: i even tried adding the sessionstart right above the session set

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: im not throwing any errors

Comment: Try to check apache log, and why you don't redirect using header("Location:")?

Comment: What about $login_ok? Are you sure that is being set to true?

Comment: header("Location:") was not working and the error is only for browsers without cookies how do i fix this or throw and error message to the user telling them to turn on cookies?

Comment: $login_ok works fine as i said i can print out session info while I'm inside of the if statement, also why wouldn't  header("Location:") be working???